# Doing a compare between field and variable in MS access - does not find match

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to delete duplicate records in MS ACCESS. 
I have created a query that is sorted on field name.

I have VBA code that runs through the query, and then when finds a match it deletes the record - however it is not picking up the match.

My code looks as follows:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim recIn As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFieldName1 As Variant
Dim strFieldDescr2 As Variant
Dim strDomainCat3 As Variant
Dim strBusinessTerm4 As Variant
Dim strtableName5 As Variant
Dim lngRecordsDeleted As Variant

lngRecordsDeleted = 0
Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set recIn = db.OpenRecordset("qryMyRecords")  
 If recIn.EOF Then
 MsgBox ("No Input Records")
 recIn.Close
 Set recIn = Nothing
 Set db = Nothing
 Exit Sub
End If
Do
  If recIn!FieldName = strFieldName1 And _
     recIn!FieldDescr = strFieldDescr2 And _
     recIn!DomainCatID = strDomainCat3 And _
     recIn!BusinessTermID = strBusinessTerm4 And _
     recIn!TableID = strtableName5 Then
     recIn.Delete
     lngRecordsDeleted = lngRecordsDeleted + 1

 Else

   strFieldName1 = recIn!FieldName
   strFieldDescr2 = recIn!FieldDescr
   strDomainCat3 = recIn!DomainCatID
   strBusinessTerm4 = recIn!BusinessTermID
   strtableName5 = recIn!TableID

  End If
recIn.MoveNext
Loop Until recIn.EOF
recIn.Close
Set recIn = Nothing
 Set db = Nothing
MsgBox ("You Deleted " & lngRecordsDeleted & " Records")

End Sub
```

My StrFieldname1, through to to StrTablename5 does populate (after the else statement)

However when I do the compare a second time

```
If recIn!FieldName = strFieldName1 And _
     recIn!FieldDescr = strFieldDescr2 And _
     recIn!DomainCatID = strDomainCat3 And _
     recIn!BusinessTermID = strBusinessTerm4 And _
     recIn!TableID = strtableName5 Then
     recIn.Delete
     lngRecordsDeleted = lngRecordsDeleted + 1
```

Even though the values are the same, it moves to the else statement, and never does the record delete.

Now I suspect that this could be because I declared my variables as VARIANT type, but if I use any other type, the code falls over every time it reaches a NULL value in the query, and there are cases where any of the fields from the query can and will be null. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have a few options when it comes to de-duplicating records in MS ACCESS - try using this link to solve your issue - https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3077791/Delete-Duplicate-Records-From-Access-Tables.htm

if you are having issues with `NULL` values you can use the `NZ` function in Access to convert any `NULL` value into something else. e.g. `NZ(<<fieldname>>, "")` - convert all `NULL` values to empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what Justin said, use the Nz function in your main `If` statement, like so:

```
If Nz(recIn!FieldName, "") = strFieldName1 And _
   ...
Else
   strFieldName1 = Nz(recIn!FieldName, "")
   ...
```